# Why do I get the message: redundant overriding method?

Tags: android-studio, inheritance, kotlin, overriding

This is not really an issue as much as I don't understand it. I'm just learning about Android Studio and Kotlin and am doing an online course in it. As instructed I used:

```
override fun onStart() {
   super.onStart()
}
```

However I get a message saying the override method is redundant and it grays out `override fun` as if it's a comment.

In the course video that doesn't happen. I assume it's some new feature of Kotlin and for some reson `override fun` does not need to be written anymore but can't find the answer online. Can anyone explain please?

This is the message I receive.

> Redundant overriding method less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> Inspection info: This inspection reports redundant override modifiers which can be omitted.

Answer (score 12):

When you extend a class, you inherit all its methods. You could override them, but here, you override a method by just calling its super's implementation, which is redundant, since you can just call the same method without overriding it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, when I started adding code to the function body the warning gone, I think you should add new code instead of just overriding onStart and its super method, also you can remove the whole function if you don't want to add code to it.

Answer (score 2):

I see this warning whenever I override a method and then don't make any changes to it.  It seems that the compiler is soooooo smart, that it say, "*Hey stupid! That code is already written for you.  So I'm going to flag it so that you know that **I know** that it's redundant.  Aren't I smart?*"

Show off.  Too bad it's not smart enough to know that you are planning on making changes very soon.